# How to know if a div is fixed to bottom?

Tags: javascript, css

http://jsfiddle.net/juveo1d7/

Is there any reliable way to know if a fixed div is positioned by setting its bottom property or its top property?

My best bet would have been getComputedStyle and thought I would know if the div is "clipped" to bottom by looking at its top property (if it's not set then the div is clipped to bottom) but even if I don't set the top property, it still returns a value in pixels.

a simple div

```
<div id="fixed"></div>
```

the css

```
#fixed {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    background: red;
}
```

and the javascript

```
var fixed = document.getElementById('fixed');
var position = window.getComputedStyle(fixed).position;
var top = window.getComputedStyle(fixed).top;
var bottom = window.getComputedStyle(fixed).bottom;
```

I know it's a minor difference but I need to reproduce the same behavior on another div using only javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the solution.

The top property returns a value in pixels in Firefox only, cause getComputedStyle acts a little differently for some properties, and returns the used value instead of the resolved value. To get the resolved value of the top property in firefox, we need to use getDefaultComputedStyle, which only exists in Firefox (since ff19).

```
var top = window.getComputedStyle(fixed).top;        // returns value in px   
var top = window.getDefaultComputedStyle(fixed).top; // returns auto
```